# Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another list

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to learn python by developing some CLI tools for my job.

I have two lists of domains, one "deduplicated" hold the full domains i've loaded from a text file, the other "poison" contains some strings partially matching some domains.

```
deduplicated = ['facebook.com','google.com','en.wikipedia.org','youtube.com','it.wikipedia.org']

poison = ['youtube','wikipedia']
```

I'm trying to match the "poison" list of strings in order to obtain two new lists, one "clean" (the domains which are not matched by the poison list) and one "dirty" (which have been partially matched").

This is my attempt but it's not working...

```
clean = []

dirty = []

for item in deduplicated:
    if (any(poison in word for word in deduplicated)):
    print ("useless domain %s" % item)
    dirty.append(item)
else:
    print ("nice domain %s" % item)
    clean.append(item)
```

**Update**:

**Edited the code because the formatting was ugly**.

For future reference, the error i was getting was:

> TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

Comment: What is your output and what is your desired output?

Comment: @mikeb i've updated the question with the error i was getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the outer loop already loops over `deduplicated`, you need the inner loop to loop over `poison`:

```
if any(search in item for search in poison):
    print("Useless domain", item)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, what you wanted to do was:

```
dirty = [word for word in deduplicated if any(unwanted in word for unwanted in poison)]
clean = [word for word in deduplicated if word not in dirty]

print(dirty) # => ['en.wikipedia.org', 'youtube.com', 'it.wikipedia.org']
print(clean) # => ['facebook.com', 'google.com']
```

There are two man problems with your code right now:

- You iterate over `item`s, but you don't use them in the check
- Your indentation is messed up. Python is sensitive to whitespaces

Comment: You are right about the iteration! The indentation was my inability to properly format the code in the Stackoverflow editor ! I'm using Sublime Text and it manages the indentation quite well.